# How to update any column from one record to another?

Tags: database, postgresql

I have two tables with identical schema. For some records I want to update from one into the other table.

Do I have to explicit set any column in the update, like:

```
UPDATE main SET colA = temp.colA, colB = temp.colB,.., colN = temp.colN FROM temp
WHERE main.id = temp.id
```

Or could I also just write somehow (as columns are all named the same):

```
UPDATE main SET <anycol> FROM temp
WHERE main.id = temp.id
```

Comment: There is no such "shortcut". You need to specify all columns

Comment: First, why do you need two columns with identical schema?

Comment: @eabraham I did not go into the detail WHY exactly I need this setup because it is irrelevant for the question itself. But as you asked, the setup is a cache engine, where I have a main DB having an optimized cache view, and a temp DB for bulk inserts of new data that still have to be processed.